# Fetching subclassed objects from Parse

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, casting

In our project, we have a class called `Attendee`, which inherits from `PFObject`. We run a `PFQuery` that fetches a list of PFObjects, which we want to store into a global `Attendee` array. Below is the code for the array and our query:

`var attendees: [Attendee] = []`

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if( error == nil ) {
                    attendees = objects as! [Attendee]
                } else {
                    println( error )
                }
            }
```

However, but when I check the contents of the attendees array in the debugger, it is always empty. Using the debugger, I checked the objects array that the is returned by the `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`, and there are objects that are being fetched.

I've also attached the `Attendee` class definition below.

```
class Attendee: PFObject, PFSubclassing {
    override class func initialize() {
        var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken) {
            self.registerSubclass()
        }
    }

    class func parseClassName() -> String {
        return "Attendee"
    }
}
```

Why is the typecast and copy to the attendees not working correctly? We are developing on Swift 1.2 and Xcode 6.3

Comment: *When* do you check the contents of the `attendees` array? Note that `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock()`, as the name indicates, works asynchronously in the background. It initiates the find operation and returns. The completion handler is called *later*, when the objects have been fetched.

Comment: Ah, I see. I think that the issue is that the `PFObjects` cannot be typecast to  `Attendee`, as the it is child of `PFObject`. Perhaps, I should implement a constructor for `Attendee` that takes a `PFObject` as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register your custom object in the AppDelegate:

`Attendee.registerSubclass()`

just before the parse initialization `Parse.setApplicationId("xxx", clientKey: "XXX")`

If you didn't, you have to init the PFQuery with the Attendee's class name:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: Attendee.parseClassName())
query.fromLocalDatastore() //if data is locally stored
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { .. }
```

These steps worked for me.

Comment: the second step without the registering the class does not work for me. also, you can use the syntax:  let query = Attendee.query(). its a bit nicer, but then you need to place ! after the query (i.e. query!.fromLocalDatastore())